# How to make one Div's position (not child or parent) completely linked / dependent on another Div's position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have a bunch of functionality for manipulating one div's position and I need another div (not child or parent) to follow any position change automatically.

Here is a very simplified illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHLD5/

```
<div id="follower"></div>
<div id="main"></div>

$('#main').draggable();
```

How to achieve this in CSS or jquery without changing html structure and without messing with selectors in `draggable()` and bunch of other codes?

So basically, how to make one div's position (not child or parent) completely linked / dependent on another div's position?

Comment: Well you've restricted yourself by saying it can't be a child. If it could be, you could give it position relative/absolute and negative left/top equal to its width/height, making it look like it's a sibling. Because it's a child, though, it will follow the parent around and give the effect you describe.

Comment: I know, but changing html structure in my case is really out of the question. If I have to, I would rather mess with selectors.

Comment: other than that, I thought that making 2 divs dependent would be fairly simple and very practical piece of code to have.

Comment: `$('#follower').appendTo('#main');` seems to be the solution. accepted answer made by suish also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#main').draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#follower').css({
      top: ui.position.top,
      left: ui.position.left
    });
  }
});
```

Another approach here

As long as you are using draggable(jQuery ui),You can easily achieve it like this.
But since the function is called alot. don't forget to use id as the selector for performance.

Comment: works, thanks. I just "discovered" another obvious and simple solution which should be certain to work with everything: `$('#follower').appendTo('#main');`

Comment: @astx123 What you are saying is changing html structure though,if you meant as "without editing html file" then that's the better way.

Comment: I just checked and you are right. I'll definitely have to use your solution because follower have to stay behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS properties for this without having to use js. You can go to [Overapi](http://overapi.com) and check exactly how they work to understand them better. In my eyes you should do something like this:

```
<div class="page_holder">
 <div class="stuck"></div>
 <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then...

```
.page_holder{
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
}
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.stuck {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  margin-right: 18px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.content {
  height:700px;
  background:gray;
}
```